# Append line every n lines to file - ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to add line to text file every 1000 line. The main issue is that file is about 3GB so I can't load the whole file to string or array. To work with big files I usually use File.foreach but I can't find any information about working with index in this case. Is there any other option to resolve this issue without the need to load whole file to memory?

Comment: `File.foreach("filename").with_index { |line, index| ... }` should work just fine.

Comment: You can also take a look at this https://radek.io/2014/01/25/word-wrap-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple options.

Option 1:

```
File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |outfile|
    File.foreach('input.txt').each_with_index do |line, i|
        outfile.puts(line)
        outfile.puts '--- 1000 ---' if (i + 1) % 1000 == 0 && i != 0
    end
end
```

This inserts the line `'--- 1000 ---'` after every 1000 lines from the original file. It has some drawbacks though. Mainly it has to check each index and check that we are not at line zero with every line! But it works. And it works on large files without hogging memory.

Option 2:

```
File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |outfile|
    File.foreach('input.txt').each_slice(1000) do |lines|
        outfile.puts(lines)
        outfile.puts '--- 1000 ---'
    end
end
```

This code does almost exactly the same thing using `Enumerable`'s `each_slice` method. It yields an array of every 1000 lines, writes them out using `puts` (which accepts `Array`s), then writes our marker line after it. It then repeats for the next 1000 lines. The difference is if the file isn't a multiple of 1000 lines the last call to this block will yield an array smaller than 1000 lines and our code will still append our line of text after it.

We can fix this by testing the array's length and only writing out our line if the array is exactly 1000 lines. Which will be true for every batch of 1000 lines except the last one (given a file that is not a multiple of 1000 lines).

Option 2a:

```
File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |outfile|
    File.foreach('input.txt').each_slice(1000) do |lines|
        outfile.puts(lines)
        outfile.puts '--- 1000 ---' unless lines.size < 1000
    end
end
```

This extra check is only needed if appending that line to the end of the file is a problem for you. Otherwise you can leave it out for a small performance boost.

Speaking of performance, here is how each option performed on a 335.5 MB file containing 1,000,000 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum. Each benchmark is total time to process the entire file 100 times.

Option 1:

```
103.859825  44.646519 148.506344 (152.286349)
[Finished in 152.6s]
```

Option 2:

```
 96.249542  43.780160 140.029702 (145.210728)
[Finished in 145.7s]
```

Option 2a:

```
 98.041073  45.788944 143.830017 (149.769698)
[Finished in 150.2s]
```

As you can see, option 2 is the fastest. Keep in mind, options 2/2a will in theory use more memory since it loads 1000 lines at a time, but even then it's capped at a very small level so handling enormous files shouldn't be a problem. However they are all so close I would recommend going with whatever option reads the best or makes the most sense.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume my results were all nearly identical here due to disk access being a bottleneck for all versions. And with buffering reading and writing 1 line or 1000 lines is probably irrelevant.

I think it still demonstrates that the different options have no _practical_ difference for what the O.P. is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and explanation. I used first option but used with_index as @Stefan adviced, this also works fine.

Comment: Note that #with_index and #each_with_index do the exact same thing except #with_index can start at a value other than zero. So if you're going to use it, you might as well use its offset parameter like so:

`File.open('output.txt', 'w') do |outfile|
 File.foreach('input.txt').with_index(1) do |line, i|
  outfile.puts(line)
  outfile.puts '--- 1000 ---' if i % 1000 == 0 && i != 1
 end
end`

It avoids having to add `1` before the the mod operation. Note I changed it to skip index `1` instead of index `0` as well.